# Migrate TYPO3 Extbase task to Symfony command

Tags: symfony, typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

I'm trying to migrate the extension [pb_social](https://bitbucket.org/plus-b/pb_social) to TYPO3 10 LTS but I'm stuck in the migration of the scheduler task that updates TYPO3 data from the social feeds.

I learned how to register a Symfony Console Command with the Services.yaml file so I can execute the command.

The problem is that the pb_social extension relies on Extbase same as its actual `updateFeedDataCommand` command.

So I tried to create a new command in the Symfony style and in its method `execute()` I instantiated:

```
$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
/** @var PBSocialCommandController $controller */
$controller = $objectManager->get(PBSocialCommandController::class);
```

I already updated the properties of pb_social methods to use the new `@TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\Inject` but still the injections seems not to work.

E.g. with:

```
/**
* @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface
* @TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\Inject
*/
protected $configurationManager;
```

$this->configurationManager is null when used.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you really need the Controller? Why not moving the required code to a service class and instantiating that instead?

Comment: @ThomasLöffler correct me if I'm wrong but it should not be relevant to the injection problem.

Comment: Even if I call the FeedSyncService directly from execute() method of the command, when  it is instanciated with `$feedSyncService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FeedSyncService::class);` the `AbstractBaseService` is instanciated but its injected `$configurationManager` property is not initialized so exception is thrown.

Comment: Even if I instanciate the FeedSyncService with `$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
        $feedSyncService = $objectManager->get(FeedSyncService::class);`... same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soved using [Method Injection](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/DependencyInjection/Index.html#method-injection)

```
/**
 * @param ConfigurationManager $configurationManager
 */
public function injectConfigurationManager(ConfigurationManager $configurationManager)
{
    $this->configurationManager = $configurationManager;
}
```